# Can the “Do you want to Open (application) from (url) prompt be avoided with ClickOnce?

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, clickonce

We would like to deploy an application via ClickOnce. But all the time the IE prombt is comin in the bottom of the page saying "Do you want to open  from "

When we set the Internet Explorer Security settings  to medium low it doesn't prompts, but when it is above medium low it always prompts. does anybody know what exacct custom settings required to disable this prompt or is there any work around to avoid it ?

Comment: There is no work around for this it an untrusted application if you do not want the browser to prompt then you need to have a valid trust certificate associated with the application.  By turning down your security setting you are allowing untrusted access to any application.

Comment: Thanks:) what is meant by Valid certificate? do you mean the code signing/SSL or any certificate should be installed in client machine.

Comment: Yes signed ssl not just any certificate.  I have never purchased a certificate so I can't help you.  But most places just informs their users that they will be prompted.  You will also be prompted when you go to run the app.  It will say not recommended to run.  The only way the get around it is to get a certificate or ask your users to add an exception to trust all from your domain in their browser.